# proxy is not working in deployed react project to github but works locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, proxy

i have a react project which makes calls to Deezer API to get some music information. there is no cors header present on server's response. so used proxy to make request to deezer api.i have setup my proxy in package.json -

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "predeploy":"npm run build",
    "deploy":"gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "proxy": "https://api.deezer.com",
```

I am making API call as follows -

```
 searchSongs= async ()=>{
         if(this.state.searchinput.length>2){
    const res = await fetch(`/search?q=${this.state.searchinput}`)
     const data = await res.json();
     console.log(data);
     this.setState({
       data:data.data
     },()=>{this.props.passSearchData(this.state.data)})
    }
```

it is working completely fine on localhost but on github i am getting this in the console and also request is not made -

GET https://prabhjot2002.github.io/api/search?q=mankirat  404
VM39:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

https://prabhjot2002.github.io/musicplay/ - this is the link to my deployed project on github.

the URL on which i want to make request is -
[https://api.deezer.com/search?query={music](https://api.deezer.com/search?query=%7Bmusic) name}

i dont have much experience in building react projects, i am just learning it , please help me ,thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy is only meant to work in dev (locally), in your case you can explicitly add the base of the url to the endpoint to solve the issue.

```
                         //add this section directly here
const res = await fetch(`https://api.deezer.com/search?q=${this.state.searchinput}`)
```

This will make it that the calls will go to the correct API endpoint.

The proxy is only useful when the base url is different in the local environment and the deployed environment.

Comment: But if i directly use the url as you said then i am having cors policy error.

Comment: That is not related to the proxy, I am unfamiliar with the specific `API` but you may need to whitelist your domain on your deezer developer account.